# PHP similar_text case sensitive

Tags: php, case-sensitive

Ok I am comparing strings using `similar_text()` but the result is being affected by the fact that it is case sensitive. Is there a way to turn this off somehow in php.ini or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the strings to lowercase which have to compared using `strtolower()`

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can tell. You could just `strtolower()` both arguments for `similar_text()`...